# Undeclared type: FDSKLoginButton

Tags: xcode, swift, fbsdk

I'm trying to implement the `FBSDK` but I keep getting an undeclared type '`FSDKLoginButton`' when in the `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    let loginButton: FDSKLoginButton = {
        let button = FDSKLoginButton()
        button.readpermissions = ["Email"]
        return button
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.center = view.center
```

How do I fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: You get FBSDK by CocoaPod?

Comment: @khuong291No I didn't, should I have?

Comment: See this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpANieebE2M